# Running two scripts that use the foreground

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to fire up an instance of elasticsearch and then an instance of kibana (which needs to wait until ES is up) using a script. I can't just do `./bin/elasticseach && ./bin/kibana` or something similar to that because the first script runs in the foreground which means the second command wont run. What's the best way I can do this while ensuring kibana only starts when ES is up and running?

Comment: Use `systemctl`. There are tools for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no way to tell when ES is up, I can only suggest:

```
./bin/elasticseach & sleep 10 && ./bin/kibana
```

Where you have to guesstimate in how much time it will be ready

Comment: Interestingly this worked without the sleep command. I just did `command1 & command2` and it did exactly what I wanted. I always thought a single `&` runs the command in the background but this didn't happen here for some reason.

Comment: There is no "background" and "foreground" per se. `echo 1 & echo 2` will print both results to the terminal. You can even run `./bin/elasticseach &` if you want to run the program and get back to the prompt without waiting for the program to end.

Comment: There is indeed a concept of running commands in the background, and the syntax for that is a single `&`. The OP can easily verify that `sleep 5 &` returns to the prompt immediately while the command continues running, whereas `sleep 5 &&` is a syntax error. For what it's worth, `&&` is the *and* operator (`false && echo yes` will not run the `echo` because `false` returns a nonzero exit code).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `./bin/elasticsearch` blocks the command line until it is 'up', you can just use a ';' between the commands to run them one after the other.

```
./bin/elasticseach; ./bin/kibana
```

But since elasticsearch just blocks the command line until stopped, you could do something else. You can run it like a daemon, so it doesn't block the command line. ([Here is the documentation about starting and stopping es](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/starting-elasticsearch.html))

```
./bin/elasticseach -d -p PID; ./bin/kibana; kill `cat PID`
```

Comment: Or, alternatively, `&&` instead of `;`, which will only start Kibana if the script exited with 0.

Comment: This doesn't work because the first command doesn't exit. ES just takes control of the foreground (with logs) until it is stopped.